# how to convert hex to arabic string

Tags: c, linux, hex

I need help writing a function to convert hex to arabic string

to Example get string this : "D8B1D8B5D98AD8AFD8A7D984D8B1D982D985"
and return this : رصيد الرقم  in english-(Balance figure).

TNX

Comment: what's your character encoding ? ISO, EBCDIC (joking) , Windows char set, Unicode ?

Comment: A Unicode/UTF-8 encoder/decoder may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with Python:

```
python -c 'print "D8B1D8B5D98AD8AFD8A7D984D8B1D982D985".decode("hex").decode("utf8")'
```

results in outputting

```
رصيدالرقم
```

That shows us that the string is a hex representation of a UTF8-encoded string.

This shows you the way you'd generally have to go.

Each of the steps must either be hand crafted in C, or taken from a library.

For hand crafting, you'll first have to

- convert the string into its "meaning" (unhexlify), and then
- convert the resulting string from UTF8 to whatever you have/need.

Comment: this good but I have only c code please